# Nginx+Passenger: rufus-scheduler not started

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, rufus-scheduler

I want to do background processing by using rufus-scheduler. It works fine on my local machine with the Webrick server but it is not working on the production server. My production server uses Nginx + Passenger.

My code is as below

```
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

scheduler.in '20s' do
  loop do
  Rails.logger.error "+++++++++++started+++++++++++"
  requests = QrCodeRequestStatus.where(:status => "pending").first(5)
  requests.each do |request|
    Rails.logger.error "+++++++++++++++++++processing request #{request.client_id} of client #{request.client_id}"
    AuthenticationCode.save_qr_codes(Client.find(request.client_id),request,request.quantity.to_i)
  end
    Rails.logger.error "+++++++++++++++sleeping+++++++++++++++++"
    sleep 5
  end
end
scheduler.join
```

I have set "PassengerSpawnMethod direct" in my Passenger config file but still, rufus-scheduler is not working.

Comment: Please read https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler#faq The "smart spawning" link might be your friend.

Comment: Please indicate in your question what version of Ruby and what version of Passenger you are using and on which platform (Linux?)

Comment: ruby version is 2.0.0 , Phusion Passenger version 5.0.11 and  Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-48-generic x86_64)

Comment: also i read the link that you have given and  as discussed in that link i put the above code in application.rb file but still it is not working

Comment: Please add the versions in your question, not in the comments. Also in the question, please add your Passenger configuration file. And remove the "scheduler.join" at the end of your Ruby code, it's meant for standalone Ruby scripts, not Ruby on Rails initializers.

Comment: configure number Thread in your server